# "This group has members, whose messages you've ignored." Is there a way to disable this popup?

Tags: facebook-messenger

I have a group chat with one member whose messages I have put in Filtered.

Every time I open the group chat, this message pops up:

> This group has members, [name], whose messages you've ignored.
>   If you ignore this group, you can find it in Filtered Messages.

It then asks if I want to ignore the group or continue.

Is there a way to block this? It's annoying to have to answer every time, especially when I could always ignore the group chat whenever I want, without a prompt.

Answer (score 2):

- I did have to message that person on our individual chat, in order to get them to be "un-ignored".
- I read that was the way to fix the problem.
- Then I thought that would help the group chat, so I wasn't getting those pop-up's.
  It didn't.

**Until I "unistalled" the app & "reinstalled" the app.**

- Now I the pop-up message about that person - is GONE! =)

I guess I just have to delete our private conversations & deal with it, in order to not get that annoying message on the group chat. :P

Good Luck,
*Jen*

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the answer.
I would still like a solution to the browser version, if anyone has it.